# How to use libav in c

Tags: c, encode, aac, libav

I have to write a c programm which is using Libav (libvo-aacenc) to encode a wav file with a bitrate given by the user (as parameter). I'm not sure what library I should include in the header. And I'm not sure how to use the libav functions in C (only in terminal). Do you have an example of C programm using libav functions?

Comment: The examples offered by Libav (e.g.: https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/encode_audio_8c-example.html ) are insufficient for your needs?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Yes, the link is useful. I just wasn't sure if if I use avconf I use at the same time "libvo-aacenc" (if avconv works without installing libvo-aacenc) because the requirement of the task is to use libvo-aacenc.